# Conexión Laravel con Sqlsrv

Tags: sql-server, laravel, odbc

Disculpen tengo un problema estoy haciendo un sistema con el  framework Laravel 
 y mi base de datos esta en SQLSRV ya configure mi php.ini  aqui dejo la evidencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi mismo ya instale el odbc, pero tengo problemas al generar mis migraciones o incluso dar de alta o hacer cualquier cosas con la base de datos. 
Ya hice una prueba de conexión a la base de datos con php nativo  para ver si me esta conectando y si me conecta  incluso cree una pequeña consulta y si corre pero al hacerlo en el framework me marca esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y al generar mi migracion sale esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi versión de php es la 5.6.32

Comment: Aún estas buscando solución para este caso??